# Is it possible to alias a computed property in a component from a controller in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to alias a computed property in a component from a controller.
The component is called comments-sidebar.js

I have tried both of the following but neither of them worked.

```
unreadCommentsOrChanges:Ember.computed.alias('comments-sidebar.unreadCommentsOrChanges'),

unreadCommentsOrChanges:Ember.computed.alias('commentsSidebar.unreadCommentsOrChanges'),
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for doing this or if it is even correct? I have not been able to find any similar examples online.

Comment: Either define the CP in the controller and pass it to the component or use DDAU approach as Ember recommends. Working against Ember will strike back sooner or later, trust me :)

Comment: `Is it possible?` Yes, it may be possible. But as Pavol mentioned, this is not the way of doing things in Ember.js.